# na.locf remove leading NAs, keep others

Tags: r, na, zoo, locf

I have a question regarding the `na.locf` function in the `zoo` package. Within the data frame below I want to remove the leading NAs (for years 1987, 1988) but keep those with a valid value for the previous year (1993).

```
Year     X
1987     NA
1988     NA
1989     2
1990     5
1991     9
1992     16
1993     NA
1994     27
1995     36
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: If 1986 is not NA, would you keep 1987?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `na.locf` is designed for filling missing observations, not removing them. The zoo package also has a `na.trim` function which removes leading and/or trailing observations:

```
na.trim(mydf)
```

which gives:

```
> na.trim(mydf)
  Year  X
3 1989  2
4 1990  5
5 1991  9
6 1992 16
7 1993 NA
8 1994 27
9 1995 36
```

With the `sides` parameter you can choose whether to remove only leading or trailing missing observations or both. Using for example `sides = 'right'` will only remove trailing missing observations and keep the leading missing observations:

```
> na.trim(mydf, sides = 'right')
  Year  X
1 1987 NA
2 1988 NA
3 1989  2
4 1990  5
5 1991  9
6 1992 16
7 1993 NA
8 1994 27
9 1995 36
```

Consequently, using `sides = 'left'` will only remove leading missing observations and keep the trailing missing observations:

```
> na.trim(mydf, sides = 'left')
   Year  X
3  1989  2
4  1990  5
5  1991  9
6  1992 16
7  1993 NA
8  1994 27
9  1995 36
10 1996 NA
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Year = 1987:1996, X = c(NA, NA, 2L, 5L, 9L, 16L, NA, 27L, 36L, NA)),
                  .Names = c("Year", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame's name is 'df'.

Convert all the NA s into a number that is invalid, say -1

```
df$X[is.na(df$X)] <- -1
```

Now do a run length encoding and remove the observations where run length of -1s are greater than 1.

```
rle(df$X)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 2 1 1 ...
  values : num [1:5] -1 2 5 ...
df$runs <- rep(rle(df$X)$lengths,rle(df$X)$lengths)

data2 <- df[!(df$X==-1 & df$runs > 1) , ]
```

Comment: Now it is clear I believe

Comment: @DavidArenburg the question states we need to keep the NA s not preceded  by NAs, but we can keep NAs surrounded by values

Comment: Maybe you right, dunno. Not sure why OP says "leading" then. This question seems unclear to me.